# How to divide in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have this code in SpringBoot

```
val num = repo.findAll().count()
val pageSize = size.get()
return Mono.just(num / pageSize)
```

But compiler show error on "/" - Unresolved reference
When I change code to:

```
val num = repo.findAll().count() as Long
val pageSize = size.get() as Double
return Mono.just(num / pageSize)
```

all compile good, but have error via request: class reactor.core.publisher.MonoCount cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (reactor.core.publisher.MonoCount is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: Hi, what data is present inside of repo.findAll().count() when running the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `num` count is not actually a `Long`, but rather a `reactor.core.publisher.MonoCount` which extends `Mono`.

Thus you only need to map the data directly:

```
return repo.findAll().count().map {
    it / size.get()
}
```